# COMO PUEDO HACER ESTE TIPO DE FORMULARIO CON ESAS LINEAS A LOS BORDES?

Tags: html, css, responsive

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<FORM>
<IMPUT LABEL> IDJQOJOFCJOPQEFJOPEQJFOPEWJOPFWJOPFJPOW
```

Mi pregunta es si puedo hacerlo directamente con html o si debo acudir también a css

Comment: con `<fieldset>` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp

Comment: ¡Hola, @lautaroo! Hay una [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12572017/4695250) en la StackOverflow en inglés que indica que `<fieldset>` es la etiqueta que buscas. El usuario original dejó el [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUMcr/1/) para ver el código utilizado y los resultados visuales. ¡Éxito!

Answer (score 0):

*"El elemento [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) (grupo de campos) permite organizar en grupos los campos de un formulario"*.

Podrías imitar el formato de este como una clase `html` que especifique los márgenes y la posición del texto de manera que se asemeje al comportamiento de `fieldset`.

```css
.fieldset {
  border: 2px groove ButtonFace;
  border-top-width: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  padding: .35em .625em .75em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

.legend {
  margin-top: -1em;
}

.legend.test::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1px;
  border-top: 2px groove ButtonFace;
  content: " ";
  width: 0.5em;
}

.legend.test::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 2px groove ButtonFace;
  content: " ";
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fieldset test">
  <div class="legend test">
    title
  </div>
  content
</div>
```